# Insert parameter from text into file

Tags: python-3.x

There's an example:

```
QRY = """SELECT * FROM {tablename}"""

today = datetime.datetime.today
table_name = "Example{0:%Y%m%d}".format(today - datetime.timedelta(days=2))
ex_query = QRY.format(tablename = table_name)
```

Trying to write this query into txt file. Text in file should be:

```
"SELECT * FROM Example20210528"" - if timedelta = 2

"SELECT * FROM Example20210527"" - if timedelta = 3
```

and so on.

This is what I tried:

```
with open("Example.txt", "w") as text_file:
text_file.write(QRY)
text_file.truncate(0)
```

But it writes into file txt without parameter, like:

```
"SELECT * FROM {tablename}"
```

How to do it correctly?

Answer (score 0):

You are writing `QRY` and not `ex_query`. If I change it to:

```
import datetime

QRY = """SELECT * FROM {tablename}"""

today = datetime.datetime.today()
table_name = "Example{0:%Y%m%d}".format(today - datetime.timedelta(days=2))
ex_query = QRY.format(tablename = table_name)

with open("Example.txt", "w") as text_file:
    text_file.write(ex_query)
```

It correctly writes: "SELECT * FROM Example20210528".

Comment: Yeah...I'm blind. Thank you

Comment: No problem. Happens to all of us.